# Get the max array from an array multidimensional based on value of column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, php-5.3

I have this array call `$aSumGame` :

```
Array
(
[682] => Array
    (
        [nature] => 682
        [totalGames] => 3
        [category] => super
    )

[707] => Array
    (
        [nature] => 707
        [totalGames] => 2
        [category] => event
    )

[728] => Array
    (
        [nature] => 728
        [totalGames] => 2
        [category] => event
    )

)
```

Now I want to get the array who have the max number of column `totalGames`, in this case I want to get the array with the key `682`. I tried like this `$aMaxGame= max($aSumGame['totalGames']);` but not work. Can you help me please ?

Comment: If there are 2 keys containing max return both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `uasort` along with `current` function like as

```
uasort($arr,function($a,$b){
    return $b['totalGames'] - $a['totalGames'];
});

print_r(current($arr));
```

You can simply use `usort` like as

```
usort($arr,function($a,$b){
    return $b['totalGames'] - $a['totalGames'];
});

print_r($arr[0]);
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/96kk0)

Comment: Wicked use of `current`!

Comment: But you're one of those user who commented for an answer and I appreciate that

Comment: I still prefer the one using `current` :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this, haven`t ran it but should be ok:

```
$array = array('682'=>array('nature'=>1,'totalGames'=>3), '707'=>array('nature'=>1,'totalGames'=>2));
$tempArray = array();
foreach($array as $id=>$array2) {
    $tempArray[$array2['totalGames']][] = $id;// store by the number of games, ex : array('2'=>array(707, 728), '3'=>array(682)
}
$maxKey = max(array_keys($tempArray)); //get the max, ex: 3
var_dump($tempArray[$maxKey]); //all id`s with max, ex: array(682)
list($oneResult) = $tempArray[$maxKey]; //get 682
var_dump($array[$oneResult]); //element from the initial array from key
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcasecmp($b['totalGames'], $a['totalGames']);
});

print_r(current($array));
```